# SELECT within UPDATE CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

New to t-sql, trying to get the following Select statement to work. Any ideas?
Cheers,
Julian

```
UPDATE DRPDATA  
SET DRPDATA.LocatieCode = CASE  
WHEN SUBSTRING([Org eenheid code],1,2) IN ('91','92','93') THEN 'BZ'  
ELSE (SELECT Huizen.IDHuis FROM DRPDATA INNER JOIN Huizen ON DRPDATA.Locatie = Huizen.NrHuis)  
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use two queries.  If you need them to be atomic, use a transaction.  You're adding a lot of complexity here for no real reason.  Running as a single statement is likely more complicated for the DB engine, too, so two statements may perform better.

```
UPDATE DRPDATA
SET DRPDATA.LocatieCode = 'BZ'
WHERE SUBSTRING([Org eenheid code],1,2) IN ('91','92','93');

UPDATE DRPDATA
SET DRPDATA.LocatieCode = Huizen.IDHuis
FROM DRPDATA
INNER JOIN Huizen 
    ON DRPDATA.Locatie = Huizen.NrHuis
WHERE SUBSTRING([Org eenheid code],1,2) NOT IN ('91','92','93');
```

Note that the `WHERE` clauses make the two queries mutually exclusive, so the order you run them will not matter.

Comment: Thank you Bacon Bits. Thanks for the explanation. On a steep learning curve here. J.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is the subquery isn't correlated and is probably returning more than the one value allowed.

You can move the join like this

```
update d
set locatiecode = case when .... end
from drpdata d
join huizen h on ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Below Query

```
UPDATE DRPDATA  
SET LocatieCode = 
        CASE  
          WHEN SUBSTRING(a.[Org eenheid code],1,2) IN ('91','92','93') THEN 'BZ'  
          ELSE   b.IDHuis END
FROM DRPDATA a INNER JOIN Huizen b ON a.Locatie = b.NrHuis
```